# Web Api of content-type XML returns complete class - while JSON returns just ID

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, json, asp.net-web-api

I have created a .net Web Api project. I already have an existing Logic and Data layer and want to expose some of the data using Web Api.  Everything works fine when the content-type returned is XML - all relevant records and all fields are returned correctly. However if I change the content-type to JSON - all relevant records are returned BUT only with the ID.

I have verified this using Fiddler and different browsers.

I could create a dumby class and hydrate it but that is a pain and a lot of work. Any ideas of what is going on?

PS The classes being returned have fields that only include simple types (99% sure).

Comment: Your types decorated with Data Contract attributes?  You using the JsonDataContractSerializer?

Comment: @Will  thanks a lot I was not using a Data Contract Attribute and as soon as I added it and DataMembers they started showing! Thanks for your time and pointer in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

@Will that was it!

I have to go back and add "[DataContract]" to my classes and "[DataMember]" to the members and the data then comes through.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127.aspx

```
namespace MyTypes
{
    [DataContract]
    public class PurchaseOrder
    {
        private int poId_value;

        // Apply the DataMemberAttribute to the property.
        [DataMember]
        public int PurchaseOrderId
        {

            get { return poId_value; }
            set { poId_value = value; }
        }
    }
}
```